# После недавних изменений, в самом начале каждой страницы перед doctype появилась строка orm-data; name="save, что это?

Tags: php, html

Внёс достаточно много правок, откатить назад уже нет возможности, а из-за этой строки тег head пустой, и она видна на самой странице, понятия не имею что это, гугл выдаёт только технологию ORM.

Правка: убрал шаблон head'a строка пропала код шаблона обычный html с подключением стилей

Comment: Вы бы хоть написали на чем именно сайт работает...framework, cms ? там бы и объяснить смогли

Answer (score 0):

Что ж, сам спросил сам ответил, я сменил расширение шаблона с html на phtml, по какой-то не известной и даже магической для меня причине (разъяснения приветствуются) всё стало работать нормально. Вывод: надо было идти работать грузчиком.